# Can't bring element to front

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, layers

In one page of my inDesign document, there's a pink rectangle. I created a text element and moved this element on this rectangle.

No matter how hard I try to send this pink rectangle to back (arrange > send to back) and bring the text element to the front (arrange > bring to front), the rectangle stays above and hides the text, as if it was on front by law. What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It could be a couple things. Check these first:

1. Is the pink box locked?
2. Is the pink box on a different layer?
3. is the pink box on a master page?

If it's locked, there will be a little lock symbol on the frame. Try Unlocking all the objects on that page by choosing  `Object > Unclock All on spread`  in the menu.

If it's on a different layer than the other objects you are trying to move it behind/in front of, it won't work unless you move the layer. The  `Arrange > Send To Back`  only works with objects on the same layer.

If the object is on a master page, you still may be able to add text to it but it will be locked by the master page. Try releasing the pink box from the master. To do this hold `Cmd+Shift` (ctrl+shift on PC) and click the pink box. Then try to arrange the objects how you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Four years later, an InDesign noob shares insight: GoofyMonkey's answer is correct for within layers but there is no obvious way to `object -> arrange -> "send to current layer"` as in Illustrator. And moving an object between layers is so easy, it is nearly impossible to Google.

1. Select your object in the page.
2. Have layers panel showing.
3. Left click and hold on the color dot at right side of layer.
4. Drag to the new layer you wish the object to be in.

[image: Use mouse to move an object between layers]

Comment: Neat I didn't know you could drag the dot.